# display functional component if input value is empty

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I'm using `DateRangePicker` from `rsuite` but I noticed it does not have a required property. Which is allows users to enter a blank date and I'm looking to prevent this from happening. Here is my code:

```
function App() {
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState('');
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

   const dateOnChange = (date) => {
    const startDate = date[0];
    const startDateString = format(startDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    console.log('Start Date:', startDateString);
    setStartDate(startDateString);
    const endDate = date[1];
    const endDateString = format(endDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    console.log('End Date:', endDateString);
    setEndDate(endDateString);
  };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const dataSubmit = { value, startDate, endDate };
    fetch('/table', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(dataSubmit),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
      });
  };


    
      return (
              <div className='App'>
                  <DateRangePicker
                    appearance='default'
                    placeholder='Select Date Range'
                    onOk={dateOnChange}
                    format='yyyy-MM-dd'
                    className='sans-fonts-all'
                  />

                  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='sans-fonts-all'>
                    <InputGroup className='w-50'>
                      <Form.Control
                        type='text'
                        required
                        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
                      />
                      <Button type='submit' className='sans-fonts-all'>
                        Get Info
                      </Button>
                    </InputGroup>
                  </Form>


    </div>
    );
}export default App;
```

I'm looking to add an if statement at the beginning of my `handleSubmit` function as the button is pressed. If the dates are empty then I wanted to render a warning that tells the user that a date is required. If the date is passed then it would hit my else portion of the statement and make to request to my backend. I'm new to React and been looking online but I'm not sure what they best approach would be. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can put validation in handleSubmit method before making the API call. But If startDate and endDate are empty then format method in dateOnChange will also throw en error.

Comment: Right, that is my intention by adding the if statement inside handleSubmit before the fetch call is made which I thought I mentioned in my initial question. I'm just trying to figure out how to render the component if the if statement is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an error state and when validation is failed then set the error state to true and render the error component.

```
const [error, setError] = useState(false);

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    /* Some code here */
    if(!startDate || !endDate) {
      setError(true)
    } else {
      setError(false);
      /* Make API call */
    }
}

return (
  /* Some JSX */
  {error && <ErrorToast />}
)
```

Comment: thank you, I definitely was overthinking this. This is what I was looking for.